# Primo Water Dispenser Suddenly Tripping Circuit Breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a top loading Primo water dispenser. Model # 601130, [found here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Primo-White-Top-Load-Water-Dispenser-601130-C/306918293) on Home Depot's website, as I couldn't find this particular model on an official Primo site.

Listed on back of dispenser:

```
Model: 601130
115V, 60Hz, 6A.
R134a/32g(1.13oz)
High side: 1.6 Mpa (232Psig)
Low side: .62 Mpa (90Psig)
```

I recently moved into a new apartment, about a month ago. I never had an issue with this dispenser in my previous home, where I lived with it for five years. It has now been sitting in my new apartment's kitchen hallway.

Today, I briefly left my house and came back to see that my bathroom power was off. I discovered a circuit breaker was tripped and it immediately tripped again when I tried to turn the breaker on. After some plugging and unplugging, I found that the water dispenser is the culprit. When I unplug it, the circuit breaker does **not** trip. It has both cooling and heating components. I have not had this issue in the time that I have lived here thus far and it is a new problem. I found the manual [online here](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/8e/8ebe9e36-f187-4d4b-9077-3ce32cb21c7e.pdf), and it says it requires a GFCI outlet. I am not sure if the problem outlet is GFCI, as it does not have a test/reset button. In fact, none of the outlets in the apartment have a test/reset button.

Is this an issue with the water dispenser or the outlet? Is it possible for outlets to be GFCI without test/reset buttons? If I don't have a GFCI outlet should I stop using this dispenser entirely?

Comment: GFCI protection can be outlets and/or breakers.  GFCI protection is only from late 80s 90s, so if if building is older might not have it.  Most of us lived without it.  Quite possible there is a short in it now, if breaker is tripping, so using without repair is not good.

Comment: It is a very new building, like constructed within the last 5 years new.

When you say short in it, a short in what do you mean?

I have plugged it into a different outlet without issue.

Comment: Hot to ground wires or hot to neutral touching.  If the outlets do not have buttons, then the breakers probably do.  Bathrooms I think were one of the first rooms to require GFCI protection, then kitchens.  There does seem to be a problem with the dispenser.  If it is a ground fault, maybe electrical insulation failing or water in the device(not where it should not be), it can be dangerous to you to touch.  Water + electricity+ people not a good mix.

Comment: Does the breaker that’s tripping have a “reset” button?

Comment: No but it does have a "test" and an indicator light. It is an Eaton circuit breaker. I'm not 100% sure if [this](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/catalog/electrical-circuit-protection/ch-circuit-breakers.html) is the same breaker but it is definitely the same brand, Eaton.

Comment: Can you post photos of the breaker in question please?